# A way to Dialogflow handle two or more intent in the same sentence

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

For instance, I've created two Intents on Dialogflow, A and B:

A - Question: It's going to rain? -> Answer: yes, it is.

B - Question: what is the color of the sky ? -> Answer: blue

If I ask separately A or B, the answer it's right, but if I ask: "It's going to rain and what is the color of the sky?" It's just answer one of the questions.

It's there a way where the dialogflow can understand the two intents?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, this feature is not present in the dialogflow (or any NLP engine i guess). Dialogflow takes an input sentence and maps it to an intent based on confidence score.
Even if you the NLP engine gives you confidence score of all the intents, you would have problem in combining them.

One solution could be making an intent C which would contain such training phrases, but that would require thorough planning about what users might ask, and what intents should be grouped together to make new intents.